# Applying Style to child elements in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, styles

In Silverlight 4 (using Expression Blend 4), how can I alter the Font size of a `TextBox` within the style of the `Border` containing it?  I'm converting the style from WPF to Silverlight (fun always).  Here is what I have:

```
<Style x:Key="Title" TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="48"/>
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextForeground}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TitleBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="25,0"/>
</Style>
```

It is not working. It gives me the following exception in the designer:
[image]

**Edits:**

Ok, I know this is possible in WPF.  Is it simply not possible in Silverlight (without taking on a whole theme construct as Xin suggests?)

Comment: i don't think it's possible to do this in Silverlight 4...

Comment: @Xin, not very helpful, but honest. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you might be able to get what you want from silverlight toolkit themes. You can find it [here](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html) (Theming -> Theme Browser).

**Update:**

First you need to create a class that inherits from the Theme (System.Windows.Controls.Theming). I basically copied from the source code and renamed it.

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Implicitly applies the border theme to all of its descendent
    /// FrameworkElements.
    /// </summary>
    /// <QualityBand>Preview</QualityBand>
    public class BorderTheme : Theme
    {
       /// <summary>
        /// Stores a reference to a Uri referring to the theme resource for the class.
        /// </summary>
        private static Uri ThemeResourceUri = new Uri("/theming;component/Theme.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the ExpressionDarkTheme class.
        /// </summary>
        public BorderTheme()
            : base(ThemeResourceUri)
        {
            var a = ThemeResourceUri;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether this theme is the application theme.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app">Application instance.</param>
        /// <returns>True if this theme is the application theme.</returns>
        public static bool GetIsApplicationTheme(Application app)
        {
            return GetApplicationThemeUri(app) == ThemeResourceUri;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets a value indicating whether this theme is the application theme.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app">Application instance.</param>
        /// <param name="value">True if this theme should be the application theme.</param>
        public static void SetIsApplicationTheme(Application app, bool value)
        {
            SetApplicationThemeUri(app, ThemeResourceUri);
        }
    }
```

Then you just need to create a resource dictionary and name it Theme.xaml, and put all your styles inside.

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style TargetType="Border"> 
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>    
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>    
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TitleBackground}"/>  
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="25,0"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>    
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>    
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="48"/>    
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextForeground}"/>
</Style> 
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Last, wrap your Border with it!

```
    <local:BorderTheme>
        <Border>
            <TextBlock Text="TextBlock"/>
        </Border>
    </local:BorderTheme>
```

That's it. You should be able to see the styles applied to your Border as well as your TextBlock. :)

Comment: I'm confused.  How does this help my situation.  I'm wanting to build a clock, and you're giving me the blue prints for a rocket ship.